# How to "reset" running SUM after it reaches a threshold?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I wrote a query that creates two columns: `the_day`, and the `amount_raised` on that day.  Here is what I have:

[image]

And I would like to add a column that has a running sum of `amount_raised`:

[image]

Ultimately, I would like the `sum` column to reset after it reaches 1 million.

The recursive approach is above my pay grade, so if anyone knows a way to reset the sum without creating an entirely new table, please comment (maybe with a RESET function?). Thank you

Comment: Show us some sample date, desire result and what have you tried. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819710/how-to-calculate-moving-sum-with-reset-based-on-condition-in-teradata-sql

Comment: Thank you for the link and asking for specifics; I have added what I have, and explained again my goal. Please let me know if I need to add more.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I have edited the question title. It would be great if you explained in more detail what you mean by "reset" of the sum. Show us an example of how the final result should look like around this 1 million mark. I tried to guess what you need in my answer, but I may have guessed wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to thank Juan Carlos Oropeza for providing a script and SQLFiddle with the test data. George, you should have done that.

The query itself it rather simple.

At first calculate a simple running sum (`CTE_RunningSum`) and divide it by `1,000,000` to get number of whole millions.

Then calculate the running sum again with partitioning by the number of millions.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98bcd/8/0)

I included the columns `RunningSum` and `Millions` in the final result to illustrate how the query works.

```
WITH
CTE_RunningSum
AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID
    ,day_t
    ,collect
    ,SUM(collect) OVER(ORDER BY day_t, id) AS RunningSum
    ,(SUM(collect) OVER(ORDER BY day_t, id)) / 1000000 AS Millions
  FROM myTable
)
SELECT
  ID
  ,day_t
  ,collect
  ,RunningSum
  ,Millions
  ,SUM(collect) OVER(PARTITION BY Millions ORDER BY day_t, id) AS Result
FROM CTE_RunningSum
ORDER BY day_t, id;
```

**Result**

```
|  id |                       day_t | collect | runningsum | millions |  result |
|-----|-----------------------------|---------|------------|----------|---------|
|  90 |     March, 11 2015 00:00:00 |   69880 |      69880 |        0 |   69880 |
|  13 |     March, 25 2015 00:00:00 |   69484 |     139364 |        0 |  139364 |
|  49 |     March, 27 2015 00:00:00 |   57412 |     196776 |        0 |  196776 |
|  41 |     March, 30 2015 00:00:00 |   56404 |     253180 |        0 |  253180 |
|  99 |     April, 03 2015 00:00:00 |   59426 |     312606 |        0 |  312606 |
|   1 |     April, 10 2015 00:00:00 |   65825 |     378431 |        0 |  378431 |
| 100 |     April, 27 2015 00:00:00 |   60884 |     439315 |        0 |  439315 |
|  50 |       May, 11 2015 00:00:00 |   39641 |     478956 |        0 |  478956 |
|  58 |       May, 11 2015 00:00:00 |   49759 |     528715 |        0 |  528715 |
|  51 |       May, 17 2015 00:00:00 |   32895 |     561610 |        0 |  561610 |
|  15 |       May, 19 2015 00:00:00 |   50847 |     612457 |        0 |  612457 |
|  66 |       May, 29 2015 00:00:00 |   66332 |     678789 |        0 |  678789 |
|   4 |      June, 04 2015 00:00:00 |   46891 |     725680 |        0 |  725680 |
|  38 |      June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |   64732 |     790412 |        0 |  790412 |
|  79 |      June, 14 2015 00:00:00 |   62843 |     853255 |        0 |  853255 |
|  37 |      June, 28 2015 00:00:00 |   54315 |     907570 |        0 |  907570 |
|  59 |      June, 30 2015 00:00:00 |   34885 |     942455 |        0 |  942455 |
|  71 |      July, 08 2015 00:00:00 |   46440 |     988895 |        0 |  988895 |
|  31 |      July, 10 2015 00:00:00 |   39649 |    1028544 |        1 |   39649 |
|  91 |      July, 12 2015 00:00:00 |   65048 |    1093592 |        1 |  104697 |
|  57 |      July, 14 2015 00:00:00 |   60394 |    1153986 |        1 |  165091 |
|  98 |      July, 20 2015 00:00:00 |   34481 |    1188467 |        1 |  199572 |
|   3 |      July, 26 2015 00:00:00 |   58672 |    1247139 |        1 |  258244 |
|  95 |    August, 19 2015 00:00:00 |   52393 |    1299532 |        1 |  310637 |
|  74 |    August, 20 2015 00:00:00 |   37972 |    1337504 |        1 |  348609 |
|  20 |    August, 27 2015 00:00:00 |   36882 |    1374386 |        1 |  385491 |
|   2 | September, 07 2015 00:00:00 |   39408 |    1413794 |        1 |  424899 |
|  14 | September, 09 2015 00:00:00 |   40234 |    1454028 |        1 |  465133 |
|   6 | September, 17 2015 00:00:00 |   65957 |    1519985 |        1 |  531090 |
|  93 | September, 29 2015 00:00:00 |   47213 |    1567198 |        1 |  578303 |
|  35 | September, 30 2015 00:00:00 |   49446 |    1616644 |        1 |  627749 |
|  86 |   October, 11 2015 00:00:00 |   34291 |    1650935 |        1 |  662040 |
|  75 |   October, 12 2015 00:00:00 |   31448 |    1682383 |        1 |  693488 |
|  19 |   October, 14 2015 00:00:00 |   48509 |    1730892 |        1 |  741997 |
|  56 |   October, 26 2015 00:00:00 |   30072 |    1760964 |        1 |  772069 |
|  48 |   October, 28 2015 00:00:00 |   58527 |    1819491 |        1 |  830596 |
|  40 |  November, 05 2015 00:00:00 |   67293 |    1886784 |        1 |  897889 |
|  33 |  November, 09 2015 00:00:00 |   41944 |    1928728 |        1 |  939833 |
|  34 |  November, 11 2015 00:00:00 |   35516 |    1964244 |        1 |  975349 |
|  85 |  November, 20 2015 00:00:00 |   43920 |    2008164 |        2 |   43920 |
|  18 |  November, 23 2015 00:00:00 |   44925 |    2053089 |        2 |   88845 |
|  62 |  December, 24 2015 00:00:00 |   34678 |    2087767 |        2 |  123523 |
|  67 |  December, 25 2015 00:00:00 |   35323 |    2123090 |        2 |  158846 |
|  81 |  December, 28 2015 00:00:00 |   37071 |    2160161 |        2 |  195917 |
|  54 |   January, 02 2016 00:00:00 |   32330 |    2192491 |        2 |  228247 |
|  70 |   January, 06 2016 00:00:00 |   47875 |    2240366 |        2 |  276122 |
|  28 |   January, 23 2016 00:00:00 |   40250 |    2280616 |        2 |  316372 |
|  65 |   January, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   49404 |    2330020 |        2 |  365776 |
|  73 |   January, 26 2016 00:00:00 |   65879 |    2395899 |        2 |  431655 |
|   5 |  February, 05 2016 00:00:00 |   53953 |    2449852 |        2 |  485608 |
|  32 |  February, 11 2016 00:00:00 |   44988 |    2494840 |        2 |  530596 |
|  53 |  February, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   68948 |    2563788 |        2 |  599544 |
|  83 |     March, 11 2016 00:00:00 |   47244 |    2611032 |        2 |  646788 |
|   8 |     March, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   51809 |    2662841 |        2 |  698597 |
|  82 |     March, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   66506 |    2729347 |        2 |  765103 |
|  88 |     April, 06 2016 00:00:00 |   69288 |    2798635 |        2 |  834391 |
|  89 |     April, 14 2016 00:00:00 |   43162 |    2841797 |        2 |  877553 |
|  52 |     April, 23 2016 00:00:00 |   47772 |    2889569 |        2 |  925325 |
|   7 |     April, 27 2016 00:00:00 |   33368 |    2922937 |        2 |  958693 |
|  84 |     April, 27 2016 00:00:00 |   57644 |    2980581 |        2 | 1016337 |
|  17 |       May, 17 2016 00:00:00 |   35416 |    3015997 |        3 |   35416 |
|  61 |       May, 17 2016 00:00:00 |   64603 |    3080600 |        3 |  100019 |
|  87 |      June, 07 2016 00:00:00 |   41865 |    3122465 |        3 |  141884 |
|  97 |      June, 08 2016 00:00:00 |   64982 |    3187447 |        3 |  206866 |
|  92 |      June, 15 2016 00:00:00 |   58684 |    3246131 |        3 |  265550 |
|  23 |      June, 26 2016 00:00:00 |   46147 |    3292278 |        3 |  311697 |
|  46 |      June, 30 2016 00:00:00 |   61921 |    3354199 |        3 |  373618 |
|  94 |      July, 03 2016 00:00:00 |   55535 |    3409734 |        3 |  429153 |
|  60 |      July, 07 2016 00:00:00 |   63607 |    3473341 |        3 |  492760 |
|  45 |      July, 20 2016 00:00:00 |   51965 |    3525306 |        3 |  544725 |
|  96 |      July, 20 2016 00:00:00 |   46684 |    3571990 |        3 |  591409 |
|  29 |    August, 09 2016 00:00:00 |   37707 |    3609697 |        3 |  629116 |
|  69 |    August, 11 2016 00:00:00 |   37194 |    3646891 |        3 |  666310 |
|  80 |    August, 19 2016 00:00:00 |   62673 |    3709564 |        3 |  728983 |
|  36 |    August, 28 2016 00:00:00 |   48237 |    3757801 |        3 |  777220 |
|  39 |    August, 29 2016 00:00:00 |   48159 |    3805960 |        3 |  825379 |
|  25 |    August, 30 2016 00:00:00 |   60958 |    3866918 |        3 |  886337 |
|  68 | September, 04 2016 00:00:00 |   50167 |    3917085 |        3 |  936504 |
|  55 | September, 08 2016 00:00:00 |   31193 |    3948278 |        3 |  967697 |
|  64 | September, 10 2016 00:00:00 |   31157 |    3979435 |        3 |  998854 |
|  42 | September, 14 2016 00:00:00 |   52878 |    4032313 |        4 |   52878 |
|  43 | September, 15 2016 00:00:00 |   54728 |    4087041 |        4 |  107606 |
|  77 | September, 18 2016 00:00:00 |   65320 |    4152361 |        4 |  172926 |
|  12 | September, 23 2016 00:00:00 |   43597 |    4195958 |        4 |  216523 |
|  30 | September, 26 2016 00:00:00 |   32764 |    4228722 |        4 |  249287 |
|  10 | September, 27 2016 00:00:00 |   47038 |    4275760 |        4 |  296325 |
|  47 |   October, 08 2016 00:00:00 |   46280 |    4322040 |        4 |  342605 |
|  26 |   October, 10 2016 00:00:00 |   69487 |    4391527 |        4 |  412092 |
|  63 |   October, 30 2016 00:00:00 |   49561 |    4441088 |        4 |  461653 |
|  78 |  November, 15 2016 00:00:00 |   40138 |    4481226 |        4 |  501791 |
|  27 |  November, 27 2016 00:00:00 |   57378 |    4538604 |        4 |  559169 |
|  21 |  December, 01 2016 00:00:00 |   35336 |    4573940 |        4 |  594505 |
|  16 |  December, 03 2016 00:00:00 |   39671 |    4613611 |        4 |  634176 |
|  22 |  December, 13 2016 00:00:00 |   34574 |    4648185 |        4 |  668750 |
|  72 |   January, 29 2017 00:00:00 |   55084 |    4703269 |        4 |  723834 |
|  44 |   January, 30 2017 00:00:00 |   36742 |    4740011 |        4 |  760576 |
|  24 |  February, 01 2017 00:00:00 |   31061 |    4771072 |        4 |  791637 |
|  76 |  February, 12 2017 00:00:00 |   35059 |    4806131 |        4 |  826696 |
|   9 |  February, 27 2017 00:00:00 |   39767 |    4845898 |        4 |  866463 |
|  11 |  February, 28 2017 00:00:00 |   66007 |    4911905 |        4 |  932470 |
```

Comment: thank you for your help with this - it is precisely what I wanted to achieve. my only issue is that when dividing by 1 million, '1' beings to populate the millions column when the 500k threshold is crossed. This must be due to rounding at .5 and up. Is there a way to disable this, so the it achieves what your result looks like? I'm using postgres sql

Comment: @George, you need to use integer division (cast the sum to `int` or `bigint` first). Also, have a close look at the result set that I included in this answer - the running sum is "reset" **approximately** around the 1 million mark - see the transition from 2 to 3 millions. This happens because the boundaries for restarting the running rum are determined by the original running sum, not by the reset running sum. This is one of the possible interpretations of the question and you didn't clarify what logic is required.

Comment: thank you for clarifying - your time is much appreciated.  I want to use the following logic: once the 1 million dollars threshold is crossed, reset the sum. For example, looking at the transition from 1 to 2 million, the rest should occur on ID 18 (Nov 23) instead of ID 85 (Nov 20).

Comment: @George, I don't know how to do it the way you want it.

Comment: However helpful this answer is, unfortunately it has a bug. See the highlighted line
|  84 |     April, 27 2016 00:00:00 |   57644 |    2980581 |        2 | 1016337 |
When we create the batches by division, the spillover in the previous batch always crops up in the next batch cumulative quantity.
I am also struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I took a look again and couldnt solve it with a Windows Function so I took the recursive aproach

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ef5d/1)**

Sample Data: `100 rows` random dates between `2015-2017` amounts between `10k - 70k`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "myTable";

CREATE TABLE "myTable" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  day_t varchar(255),
  collect integer NULL
);

INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-04-10',65825),('2015-09-07',39408),('2015-07-26',58672),('2015-06-04',46891),('2016-02-05',53953),('2015-09-17',65957),('2016-04-27',33368),('2016-03-25',51809),('2017-02-27',39767),('2016-09-27',47038);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2017-02-28',66007),('2016-09-23',43597),('2015-03-25',69484),('2015-09-09',40234),('2015-05-19',50847),('2016-12-03',39671),('2016-05-17',35416),('2015-11-23',44925),('2015-10-14',48509),('2015-08-27',36882);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2016-12-01',35336),('2016-12-13',34574),('2016-06-26',46147),('2017-02-01',31061),('2016-08-30',60958),('2016-10-10',69487),('2016-11-27',57378),('2016-01-23',40250),('2016-08-09',37707),('2016-09-26',32764);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-07-10',39649),('2016-02-11',44988),('2015-11-09',41944),('2015-11-11',35516),('2015-09-30',49446),('2016-08-28',48237),('2015-06-28',54315),('2015-06-09',64732),('2016-08-29',48159),('2015-11-05',67293);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-03-30',56404),('2016-09-14',52878),('2016-09-15',54728),('2017-01-30',36742),('2016-07-20',51965),('2016-06-30',61921),('2016-10-08',46280),('2015-10-28',58527),('2015-03-27',57412),('2015-05-11',39641);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-05-17',32895),('2016-04-23',47772),('2016-02-25',68948),('2016-01-02',32330),('2016-09-08',31193),('2015-10-26',30072),('2015-07-14',60394),('2015-05-11',49759),('2015-06-30',34885),('2016-07-07',63607);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2016-05-17',64603),('2015-12-24',34678),('2016-10-30',49561),('2016-09-10',31157),('2016-01-25',49404),('2015-05-29',66332),('2015-12-25',35323),('2016-09-04',50167),('2016-08-11',37194),('2016-01-06',47875);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-07-08',46440),('2017-01-29',55084),('2016-01-26',65879),('2015-08-20',37972),('2015-10-12',31448),('2017-02-12',35059),('2016-09-18',65320),('2016-11-15',40138),('2015-06-14',62843),('2016-08-19',62673);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-12-28',37071),('2016-03-25',66506),('2016-03-11',47244),('2016-04-27',57644),('2015-11-20',43920),('2015-10-11',34291),('2016-06-07',41865),('2016-04-06',69288),('2016-04-14',43162),('2015-03-11',69880);
INSERT INTO "myTable" (day_t,collect) VALUES ('2015-07-12',65048),('2016-06-15',58684),('2015-09-29',47213),('2016-07-03',55535),('2015-08-19',52393),('2016-07-20',46684),('2016-06-08',64982),('2015-07-20',34481),('2015-04-03',59426),('2015-04-27',60884);
```

Create a `row_number` to perform the recursion need consecutive `ID's`

```
CREATE TABLE sortDates as
   SELECT day_t,
          collect,
          row_number() over (order by day_t) rn
   FROM  "myTable";
```

**Recursive Query**

If you see the `CASE` if previous total `m.collect` is bigger than 1 million the total is reset.

```
WITH RECURSIVE million(rn, day_t, collect) AS (
    (
        SELECT rn, day_t, collect
        FROM sortDates
        WHERE rn = 1         
    )
    UNION 
    (
        SELECT s.rn, s.day_t, CASE WHEN m.collect > 1000000 THEN s.collect 
                                   ELSE m.collect + s.collect
                              END as collect
        FROM sortDates s
        JOIN million m
          ON s.rn = m.rn + 1        
    )    
)
SELECT *
FROM million
WHERE collect > 1000000
```

Finally just bring the rows where you break the 1 million limit.

**OUTPUT**

```
| rn |      day_t | collect |
|----|------------|---------|
| 19 | 2015-07-10 | 1028544 |
| 41 | 2015-11-23 | 1024545 |
| 62 | 2016-05-17 | 1027511 |
| 82 | 2016-09-15 | 1006441 |
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What if I simplify so I don't need to reset after the 1 million. In other words, just have a running sum in the "sum" column? Can a window function accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, that is very easy `SELECT day_t,
     SUM(collect) over (order by day_t) as collect_total
 FROM  "myTable"`, you can test it on the fiddle

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Really? `the_day == day_t`  and `amount_raised == collect` and `sum == collect_total `

Comment: I can't get the window function to work for my data. If you use my example, with the desired data. I am simply getting a column with the same amounts as the amount_raised column

Comment: I rewrote my original question

Comment: what version of postgres are you using? Can you prepare the sql fiddle demo with your data?

Comment: my apologies, I found my error and have corrected it. I appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Glad you solve it. Hope the recursive function Isnt too complicated :)

Comment: unfortunately, the recursive approach is above my pay grade, so I just did a running sum column and looked for each 1 million increment. If anyone knows a way to reset the sum without creating an entirely new table, please comment. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for providing a script and SQL fiddle. This can be done without recursion, just calculate running sum twice. See my answer.