# Window function to achieve running sum that resets in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I've asked this question before, but the only answer was very complicated. I'm hoping that someone can help with a simpler solution. Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799247/postgres-sql-window-function) to my initial question. Here is my table of data:

[image]

I got that output by using the following code:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', el.paid_at) as the_day, round(sum(el.amount::numeric/100),0) as amount_raised, sum(round(sum(el.amount::numeric/100),0)) OVER (order by date_trunc('day', el.paid_at)) as sum FROM extended_lineitems el WHERE el.paid_at is not null and el.istip is FALSE GROUP BY the_day ORDER BY the_day
```

I would like the "sum" column to reset when it eclipses 1,000,000. You'll see in the link to my previous question that a user posted a recursive approach. I was unable to mimic that, and hope that there is another way around it.

Comment: Your condition is unclear. What does it mean to reset the column? How would the row with sum > 1M be treated? Should it create 2 separate rows? Should the rest of the amount disappear magically after reaching 1M? Should it pass onto the next amount (row) in order? Should it remain with >1M value?

Comment: You have been asked to provide data as text, not as image. Your version of Postgres is missing and I don't see table definitions with data types and constraints. Please improve your original question.