Grouping transactions based on limiting rule's
I need to write a SQL script that groups transactions for each client based on the following rules

Each group has a limit of 500000 transactions or 365 days span whatever comes first

I have three columns transaction_id, transaction_date and client_id

The result must be showing group_id, client_id, number_of_transaction_in_group, group_start_date and group_end_date


I tried this script from ChatGPT but it does not return the proper result, as shown here:



ClientId
GroupId
TransactionsInGroup
GroupStartDate
GroupEndDate




8
0
33101
2022-08-14
2023-08-13


8
1
966899
2023-08-14
2024-05-07


8
2
500000
2024-05-07
2024-08-12


8
3
417142
2024-08-12
2024-11-27



The expected result should be something like that



ClientId
GroupId
TransactionsInGroup
GroupStartDate
GroupEndDate




8
0
33101
2022-08-14
2023-08-13


8
1
500000
2023-08-14
2024-05-07


8
2
500000
2024-05-07
2024-08-12


8
3
417142
2024-08-12
2025-08-12


8
4
300000
2025-08-13
2026-08-12



Code:
WITH NumberedTransactions AS 
(
   -- Assign a row number for each transaction per client, ordered by date
   SELECT 
       ClientId,
       TransactionId,
       TransactionDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS RowNum
   FROM 
       Transactions
),
GroupsByTransactionCount AS 
(
   -- Group transactions into sets of 5 based on RowNum
   SELECT
       ClientId,
       TransactionId,
       TransactionDate,
       (RowNum - 1) / 5 AS TransactionGroup
   FROM 
       NumberedTransactions
),
GroupsByDate AS  
(
   -- Assign a start date for each 365-day window for each client
   SELECT
       ClientId,
       TransactionId,
       TransactionDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TransactionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId), TransactionDate) / 365 AS DateGroup
   FROM 
       NumberedTransactions
),
FinalGroups AS 
(
   -- Combine both grouping methods into one
   SELECT
       ClientId,
       TransactionId,
       TransactionDate,
       TransactionGroup,
       DateGroup,
       -- Use the larger group number to ensure both conditions are met
       CASE 
           WHEN TransactionGroup >= DateGroup 
               THEN TransactionGroup
           ELSE DateGroup
        END AS FinalGroup
    FROM
        GroupsByTransactionCount 
    INNER JOIN 
        GroupsByDate ON GroupsByTransactionCount.ClientId = GroupsByDate.ClientId
                     AND GroupsByTransactionCount.TransactionId = GroupsByDate.TransactionId
)
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    FinalGroup,
    COUNT(*) AS TransactionsInGroup,
    MIN(TransactionDate) AS GroupStartDate,
    MAX(TransactionDate) AS GroupEndDate
FROM 
    FinalGroups
GROUP BY 
    ClientId, FinalGroup
ORDER BY 
    ClientId, FinalGroup;


Please provide example data

Provide a complete [mcve].

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/aElkZ9e2     Now I need to figure out how to trigger new groups for Transactions #6 and #10.

Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799247/how-to-reset-running-sum-after-it-reaches-a-threshold

I think we can calculate 500k transaction and and 365day chunks this way: https://dbfiddle.uk/oen3zPon

Summarized https://dbfiddle.uk/117rCLxg

Help us so we can help you, provide the sample data that produced your expected outcome

There is no way we will be able to test an example from you that has over 500K+ transactions per customer. I suggest you make an example that tests a 5 transaction limit. If it works then just add 5 zeros.

Does the 365 day rule apply backward from the "most recent record" for each client?  e.g. is this correct? if the most recent record of client 1 is 12th Oct 20204 (2024-10-12) , then you would only include data >= 13th Oct 2023 (2023-10-13) (& ignoring the quantity of rows rule)

try setting-up required test cases using 5 instead of 500,000 - there is an attempt here https://dbfiddle.uk/yx1mp5sf
